# Button next to Mailchimp box

Tags: css, mailchimp

On this page: http://www.christophelouage.be/category/blog/

I don't succeed in putting the red 'OK' button in the sidebar to the right of the input box. I tried for hours, no luck.

This is the code of the widget:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://christophelouage.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=b665c89ed961eb5c803a3b5b8&amp;id=8b20a6157e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" novalidate>

<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Vul je e-mailadres in">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_b665c89ed961eb5c803a3b5b8_8b20a6157e" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="OK" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="blogbutton"></div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

And this is my css:

```
.mc-field-group {
    margin-top: -30px !important;
}

.mc-field-group label {
    display: none !important;
}

.mc-field-group input {
    width: 62% !important;
    clear: none !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    float: left !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #707070 !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px !important;
}

#mc_embed_signup form {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0% !important;
}

.blogbutton {
    width: 20% !important;
    clear: none !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    float: left !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px !important;
    background-color: #ad1e1c !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    border: none !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    padding: 11px 0px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    line-height: 1 !important;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
    margin-top: 2px !important;
    margin-left: 5px !important;
    text-transform: none !important;
}

.blogbutton:hover {
    background-color: #373837 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    border: none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Thanks so much for helping me out!
Stefaan

Comment: please add screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, Maintenance plugin was still active. Link should work now.

Comment: please reproduce this in a fiddle, or else once resolved your question will become obsolete and totally useless for future users.

Comment: can i move your elements perhaps? because your 62% `input` will NOT do with a outer `div`

Comment: Fiddle added: http://jsfiddle.net/573Qk/

Answer (score 3):

I moved the "OK" button within the `.mc-field-group`

```
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label><br>
    <input name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Vul je e-mailadres in" type="email">
    <input value="OK" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="blogbutton" type="submit">
</div>
```

### Extra Modified CSS:

```
.mc-field-group .blogbutton {
    position: absolute;  /*This and the one after is used to style the position of the button, may be removed*/
    top: 14px;
    width: 30% !important;
    padding: 7px !important;
}

.mc-field-group input.required {
    width:70% !important;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

### Finished Effect

[image: Finished Effect]

Please modify your own code! I can't do anything with your crazy `!important`s but you get my idea? :D

Comment: please select the "tick" if this solves your problem. it would do a lot. :)