# Subscribe Form Field and Button on Same Line

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I am trying to style a mailchimp subscribe form with just an email field and submit button. I want to have them both on the same line, but nothing I seem to try is working. It is for use inside a fancybox popup on a Wordpress platform (if that information turns out to be relevant). I've tried floating the field left and the button right, with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Code Below:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
#mc_embed_signup input.email {display: block;
padding: 8px 0;
margin: none !important;
text-indent: 5px;
width: 58%;
min-width: 130px;}

#mc_embed_signup input.button { 
float: right; 
position: relative; 
top: -25px; 
} 
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://entertainment.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?9" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <input style="float:left;" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <input style="float:right; margin-right:75px;" type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_7b66660df" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>

</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `position: relative;` to `#mc_embed_signup input.email`?

Comment: Also, try setting `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;`.

Comment: Hey @ChrisMukherjee - I just tried both of your suggestions, and still no luck : \

Comment: I will also note that when previewing the live code from Dreamweaver, they show up on the same line. However, on the site inside the fancybox popup the button floats right but on the line below...

Comment: I pasted your code into a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4cyx/. Seems to work with no changes, except removing the `top: -25pm;`. Something else must be going on in some other code running on the site

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button next to Mailchimp box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380927/button-next-to-mailchimp-box)